# Cannot injection dependency with multiple generic types in unity asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

Basically I am having trouble with trying to inject a dependency so I can make a cache in my mvc 5 app using Unity Dependency Injection. I have successfully made other dependencies which have less generic types and worked perfectly such as

```
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(CacheManager.Core.ICacheManager<IEnumerable<HourViews>>), CacheFactory.Build <IEnumerable < HourViews >> (
           p => p.WithSystemRuntimeCacheHandle()));
```

However when I try to make another similar dependency with more generics the application breaks as shown below.

```
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(CacheManager.Core.ICacheManager<IEnumerable<Daily<Overview>>>), CacheFactory.Build<IEnumerable<Daily<Overview>>>(
           p => p.WithSystemRuntimeCacheHandle()));
```

This has confused me quite a bit and I've been scratching my head about it all day. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Was any exception thrown?

Comment: No exception was thrown but the content just didnt appear like it did for all the others.Thank you.